# Freemarker equivalent of <tiles:insertAttribute name="contentName" />

Tags: tiles, freemarker

Could you please tell me what is the freemarker equivalent tag of < tiles:insertAttribute name="contentName" /> ? I have tried out with <@tiles.insertAttribute name="contentname" /> and it throws error(as freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression tiles is undefined).

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell FreeMarker what `tiles` is, e.g. by retrieving the Tiles taglib from the `JspTaglibs` hash. You probably want to read [the section about FreeMarker, servlets and taglibs from the FreeMarker manual](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html#autoid_56).

Answer (score 0):

from this example: http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/struts/src/apps/showcase/src/main/webapp/tiles/layout.ftl.shtml

```
<#assign tiles=JspTaglibs["http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"]>
...

<@tiles.insertAttribute name="header" />
```